# How to proceed? matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

[image]

I am currently in this step, but i dont know where to go from here

[image]
The original equation is this

[image]
and this is my solving, am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

We should use $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$, notice the swap of order.
$$(X^TA)^T+2BX=5X$$

$$A^TX+2BX=5X$$

$$(A^T+2B-5I)X=0$$

Hopefully you can solve for $X$ from here.

Comment: thanks!, i had the identity wrong as you noticed haha